# Function creation from a formula

Tags: r, function, formula

I need help with the creation of a function in R. my dataset is this one:

| Date | Plot | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-30 | P1 | 12 |
| 2022-03-30 | P2 | 32 |
| 2022-03-30 | P3 | 15 |
| 2022-04-04 | P1 | 22 |
| 2022-04-04 | P2 | 10 |
| 2022-04-04 | P3 | 8 |
| 2022-04-18 | P1 | 14 |
| 2022-04-18 | P2 | 13 |
| 2022-04-18 | P3 | 17 |

I want to make a function to do the following process and add the result in a new column:

y = ((12 + 22) / 2) * ((2022-04-04) - (2022-03-30)) = 110

in the las three rows wont include the date:

((14 + 13) / 2) = 13.5

| Date | Plot | Value | y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-30 | P1 | 12 | 110 |
| 2022-03-30 | P2 | 32 | 117.5 |
| 2022-03-30 | P3 | 15 | 92.5 |
| 2022-04-04 | P1 | 22 | 224 |
| 2022-04-04 | P2 | 10 | 126 |
| 2022-04-04 | P3 | 8 | 154 |
| 2022-04-18 | P1 | 14 | 13.5 |
| 2022-04-18 | P2 | 13 | 15 |
| 2022-04-18 | P3 | 17 | 8.5 |

How can I create a function to make this process or what would be another way to do it?

Comment: Do you know how to create any other function? What was the problem when you tried to create this particular function?

Comment: In your pseudocode, when you write `2022-04-04` do you mean the `Value` value when `Date` is `"2022-04-04"`? So `Value[Date == "2022-04-04"]`? Or by `(2022-04-04) - (2022-03-30)` do you mean the difference (in days?) between those two dates?

Comment: And, based on the values `12` and `22` that you use as an example, it seems like you want this to be done grouped by `Plot`? For sequential dates?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Sorry, my mistake im doing the process in R only. I want to create the formula, but im new to using R, and I don't understand the creation of a function that can include the process shown in the question. So there is a process that does what is described in the formula in R?. I can only think of developing a new function that does this, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: @GregorThomas According to your first question, the formula is the difference in days between two days, as you mentioned, and the second question is correct and has to be grouped by the plot for sequential dates. Sorry, I forgot to mention it in the description. If you know how to do this, I will be grateful.